# Why do I get a down-vote for every question I ask?

Tags: support, serial-voting

Is this serial downvoting? Every single question I have asked has got a down vote; basically, every time I ask a question, it gets down-voted,  even if they are not bad questions, since they get upvoted again. Is this strange?

Actually, it is not every single question.

Comment: Just to nit-pick and be precise, ' *they are not bad questions since they get upvoted* ' - an up vote doesn't mean a question isn't a bad question. It simply means one person thought it was worth an up vote (maybe for sympathy), dozens of others may still want to down vote it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As of right now, I see three questions asked on your Stack Overflow account:

- [How do you release memory in xcode 4.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7734502/how-do-you-release-memory-in-xcode-4-2) (no downvotes)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747567/can-you-implement-two-files-in-one-m-file (one downvote)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7734359/can-you-make-a-virtual-joystick-for-the-iphone-in-xcode (one downvote, closed)

So it's not *every* question, it's two. And one should be obvious by the close reason:

> #### closed as not a real question by Josh Caswell, Robert Harvey♦ yesterday
>
> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.
>   See the FAQ.

For the other one, it's offset by an upvote, so I'm not sure what the concern is: a single person didn't think your question was useful and someone even disagrees with them.

What you see here is not serial down-voting: it's voting as it was intended to be used.

Try not to sweat the small stuff like this: just focus on [writing the best possible question you can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).